# Is there a known distribution for event familiarity/novelty as a function of time?

Tags: probability, distributions

As we go through life, we see fewer and fewer things *for the first time*.  As time goes on, the *events* we encounter more often resemble events we've come across before.

Picture a world where we somehow know the Zipf-like probability distribution of all events.  As in, if the slice labelled "sun rising" in this distribution's PMF happens to be 0.01, it means that given a huge amount of time, and if we took all events a person went through in that time, the "sun rising" events would make up 1% of the total.  Assume in this world that events occur one by one (i.e. no Poisson stuff going on here).  An event like "winning the lottery" would be closer to zero in the PMF.

We can group events together according to their popularity.  Events that occur roughly the same number of times have the same popularity.  Furthermore, we can plot these popularity groups on a graph, like below.  I created this graph to illustrate the idea introduced earlier: as time goes on, novel events are fewer.  The portion of events occurring for the first time (the left-most part of the graph) travels downwards.

[image]

Given a final PMF for events, is there any existing probability distribution that describes the way the curve in the above plot travels downwards over time (particularly the left-most peak)?

This problem reminds me a little of the "without replacement" notion in other probability distributions (e.g. hypergeometric).  However, unlike with those distributions, as time goes on, we are not depleting items for selection, we are in fact accumulating higher probabilities of collision, thereby increasing the likelihood of familiar events occurring, decreasing the likelihood of novel events occurring.  I.e. it seems intuitive that the expected proportion of events with popularity=1 will go down as a function of time, given that events can only enter the popularity=1 bin once ever, whereas those events then have numerous opportunities to exit the popularity=1 bin.

Comment: you may be interested in Zipf's distribution https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipf%27s_law

Comment: I cam across this distribution.  However, I think it fails to capture the process I'm describing here.  Ideally, the distribution function I'm interested finding would actually take as input a Zipf-like vector of event probabilities (or counts), along with a discrete time variable (representing how many events have ticked by).  The function would then spit out the novelty-familiarity distribution at the given time-point with the given event probabilities, i.e. a slice from a plot like the above.